# Regex - Extract all text except square brackets and their contents

Tags: regex, parsing, text, changelog

I have a changelog that has the version numbers in square brackets like this:

`## [0.3.0] - 2016-12-13
- FIX This is an example fix
- FEATURE An example feature`

I want to extract **only** the version numbers so I am left with:

`[Unreleased]
[0.3.0]
[0.2.4]
[0.2.3]`

Ideally I'd like to extract only the first value in square brackets that isn't 'Unreleased' so I get the latest version number 0.3.0 although I'm not sure this is possible in regex.

Can anyone help? Thanks :)

Comment: What tool/language are you using?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what about your attempt does not meet your needs?

Comment: `(\[.*?\])` Try this.

Comment: I'm confused - your title says "Remove all..." but your question says "extract only...". Remove and extract are two different things. Which is it?

Comment: Thanks @ClasG I've updated my title :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
.*(\[.*?\]).*
```

With the replacement string: `\1`

Btw, if you want to remove all the other text, then you can use:

```
.*(\[.*?\]).*|*
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/x0w2OJ/1)**

Update: if you want to transform the changelog in a list of versions, I could come up with this regex:

```
.*(\[.*?\])[\s\S]*?(^$|\z)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/x0w2OJ/2)**

Comment: `[^[\r\n]+(?:\R[^[\r\n]+)*\R?|(\[[^]]*\])` should be a performance improvement for your last regex. `[^[\r\n]+|(\[[^]]*\])` for the one before.

Comment: @SebastianProske, very nice to know. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Edit (misread at first):

Replace

```
[\s\S]*?(\[[\d.]+])[\s\S]*
```

with

```
\1
```

[Check out this example at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iTlFhK/2).